# Text selection operation are rendered by Emacs very slow

Tags: emacs

I dont know why but after migration to Fedora16.1 + Emacs 23.3.1, text selection operations are very slow. So for example if I press Ctrl+Space for put mark and will fast press  to arrow, selection area rendered very slow and I need waiting for few seconds before it reaches current cursor position? 
May be You have idea why it might happen?

Comment: Sorry, I find mistake. I was used transient-mark-mode on, this package make annoying things.

Comment: Francis: Meta says general Emacs questions are okay on S.O.

Comment: Rustem: If that fixed the issue, add your solution as an Answer, and then Accept it.

Comment: @FrancisUpton, [Unix SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) will almost certainly get you better answers than superuser.

Comment: @ohils, I can do it after 8 hours from now :(